# Hide fields in Openerp 7 Fields - XML

Tags: python, odoo

I'd like to adapt the module purchase requisition for a company.

To achieve that i need to hide some elements of this module.

On OpenErp 6, i know you can add "position="replace".

```
<field name="name" class="oe_inline" position="replace"/>
```

On OpenErp 7 this can no longer be done.

What is the actual method to do this on OpenErp 7?

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance!

---

Arya, thank you but it doesn't hide the field

Look at this:

```
 <group>
       <field name="date_start" position="attributes"/>
       <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
       <field name="date_end" position="replace"/>
       <field name="warehouse_id" widget="selection" groups="stock.group_locations"/>
       <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" widget="selection"/>
 </group>
```

I need for example to hide just one field here, to make the test, but it doesn't actually hides it, it show then a 'True' word before the "date_end".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like

```
<group>
       <field name="date_start" position="attributes"><!--removed / from the end-->
       <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
       </field>
       <field name="date_end" position="replace"/>
       <field name="warehouse_id" widget="selection" groups="stock.group_locations"/>
       <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" widget="selection"/>
 </group>
```

Comment: Super mega awesome! Thank you very much! You rock!

Answer (score 3):

`position="replace"` is still working with v7.

If you don't want to **replace** the field, you can add `invisible="True"` attribute in field.

Like this:

```
<field name="name"  position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
</field>
```

Make sure you are inheriting the correct xml.

Comment: Look at my own answer, please :)

Answer (score 1):

You close the tag of the field before change the attribute

```
<group>
       <field name="date_start" position="attributes">
           <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
       </field>
       <field name="date_end" position="replace"/>
       <field name="warehouse_id" widget="selection" groups="stock.group_locations"/>
       <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" widget="selection"/>
 </group>
```